# How to join enumerated values in python?

Tags: python

### How to join enumerated values in python?

I was making this secret code generator but I'm unable to join the value `s` to make words in this "Secret Language" which is basically a dictionary!

---

Code:

```
secret = input("What text do you want to generate as a  secret code? ")
secretlang = {
  'a':'m',
  'b':'t',
  'c':'i',
  ...
}
for i, v in enumerate(secret): 
  print(secretlang[v])
```

Comment: What do you mean by join? could you provide an example of the expected output given what you've provided?

Comment: My output is coming up as- What text do you wnat to generate as a  secret code? secret
b
y
i
x
y
n

Comment: I want to put it together in one string

Comment: What does that have to do with `enumerate`? You're not using `i` anywhere.

Comment: Well... It's just there!

Comment: Here is the link to the updated Repl: [Repl](https://repl.it/repls/LightpinkShamelessFrontpage#main.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.join()`:

```
secret = input("What text do you want to generate as a secret code? ")
secretlang = {
  'a':'m',
  'b':'t',
  'c':'i',
  ...
}

print(''.join([secretlang[v] for v in secret]))
```

There would be an error if the user inputs characters that are not in the dictionary. 
You can ignore those by using `dict.get()`:

```
print(''.join([secretlang.get(v, v) for v in secret]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful anwser

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need `enumerate`.

```
secret = "This question was asked on StackOverflow"
secretlang = {
    "a": "m",
    "b": "t",
    "c": "i",
}

secret_string = "".join([secretlang.get(char, char) for char in secret])

print(secret_string)
```

Output:

---

```
This question wms msked on StmikOverflow
```

---